# How to use modulus with a global variable and namespace std?

Tags: c++, modulus

Yes I know `using namespace std` is bad practice, but I have already written a majority of the code with this declaration in place, and I don't think I have the time to go back and modify it.

The reason for the global variable is that I'm using multiple threads which need access to this variable and need to modify it.

My question is, I have `int remainder = 0;` declared globally, and within my master thread I call `remainder = 13 % 5;` for example.

This gives me an error saying `'int remainder' redeclared as a different kind of symbol` and I've read that the reason is that `using namespace std` overrides the `std::modulus` operator, if I understood that correctly.

What other methods can I use to perform this function, keeping `using namespace std` and `remainder` as a global variable?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int remainder = 0; 
void testing();

int main(){
    testing();
    cout << remainder << endl;
    return 0;
}

void testing(){
    remainder = 13 % 5;
}
```

Comment: Where did you read that? Also, please include as part of the question a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Please be more specific than "gives me an error". (And post a [mcve]  instead of a vague description of your code.)

Comment: `std::modulus` is not pulled in unless you use `#include <functional>`, and even then it doesn't override the actual `%` operator anyway.  `std::modulus` is a functor that uses `%` internally. It is useful for predicates and templates and such. What errors are you actually getting? They are related to something else. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your error.

Comment: Unrelated, but what are you doing to protect this global variable from race conditions?

Comment: And does this bit of code you've put in (that doesn't do any of the threading stuff) actually give you the same error (which error you'll need to include).

Comment: Can't reproduce.   The code you have shown does not produce the error you describe.

Comment: To protect global variables I am using semaphores and the threading portion is not what is throwing the error but rather it was simply the name of the variable itself as pointed out by Blastfurnace and Phil M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your global variable name conflicts with [`std::remainder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder) from the standard library. [Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/wo2-d9).

The problem with `using namespace std;` is that it brings so many symbols into the global namespace that this error is almost inevitable. It's a bad practice for anything but the simplest toy programs.

Comment: Ahhh okay I see. The error I got was *remainder was redeclared as a different kind of symbol* and it was vague enough for me that I did not understand it was referring to the name of the variable itself. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

The conflict is with `std::remainder`, not with `%`. The variable name you've chosen conflicts with a function in the `std` namespace. You already know `using namespace std;` is bad, so I'll spare you.

Options:

1. Lose the `using` statement.
2. Rename the `remainder` variable.
3. Put the `remainder` variable in its own namespace, and explicitly refer to it through that namespace.

Comment: Actually `<cmath>` almost everywhere pulls `remainder` into global namespace also, so not `using namespace std` won't solve the problem in this case.

Comment: @yachoor Apparently doesn't do so on clang 7 (used by Repl.it), Have't yet found any on goldbolt that act as you describe, but then I've only been trying the most recent versions there.

Comment: Yeah the solution seems to be renaming the variable itself as Blastfurnace and Phil M both pointed out. Thank you!

Comment: @PhilM This is what I meant: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6a92fl - no using, still can't have remainder in global namespace (all extern names from C library are reserved in both std and global namespace)

Comment: @yachoor Ah, yeah, you're correct. I apparently was testing with the wrong code. Typical, heh.